# Can connect to esp8266 AP which is connected to Arduino UNO but no response

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, android

I am new to arduino and am trying to connect the esp8266 to arduino UNO and send commands to the arduino using an android phone. 
I have double, triple checked the connections and I am sure they are 100% correct. I have connected esp GND to arduino GND, esp VCC to arduino 5V, esp TX to arduino SoftwareSerial RX and esp RX to arduino SerialSoftware TX and CH_PD to 5V. I can connect to esp using my phone but I can't send commands to it. I am using TCP/UDP Terminal on android to test the connection. Phone is connected to the AP but in the app it is not. I configured the app with 192.168.4.1 IP and 333 Port and I know that app works correctly because I have tested its integrity several times before. 
I have searched so much and tried so many but non worked.

**My code:**

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial ESP8266(2,3);

boolean FAIL_8266 = false;

#define BUFFER_SIZE 128
char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600); 
  ESP8266.begin(115200);  // change this value to your wifi module (esp8266) baud rate

  do{
  ESP8266.println("AT");
    delay(1000);
    if(ESP8266.find((char*)"OK"))
    {
      Serial.println("Module is ready");
      delay(1000);

      //configure ESP as AP 
      Serial.println("AT+CWMODE=2");
      delay(1000);

      //Set multi connections
      Serial.println("AT+CIPMUX=1");
      delay(1000);

      Serial.println("Server setup finish");
      delay(1000);

      FAIL_8266 = false;

    }
    else{
      Serial.println("Module have no response.");
      delay(500);
      FAIL_8266 = true;
    }
  }while(FAIL_8266);

  ESP8266.setTimeout(100); 

}

void loop() {

  if(ESP8266.available()){
    String msg = ESP8266.readString();
    Serial.println("MSG: "+msg);
  }
}
```

Could anyone please tell me what is wrong?

Comment: You can't use SoftwareSerial reliably at 115200 baud. The Arduino just can't keep up with the speed to the data coming in. That said, you should write a simple serial echo program to allow you to communicate with the esp8266 manually via the Arduino to test that communication is actually happening.

Comment: @Majenko Thanks about the answer, I did a little research about what you said on the internet and it looks correct. I have read about changing the esp8266 baudrate to a lower amount but I didn't do it because many have reported that doing it have bricked their esp8266. Now, do you have anything in mind to fix the problem?

Comment: You really want to reduce the ESP8266 baud rate. You should get yourself set up for reflashing the ESP8266 first though. It's something you should get into anyway - it's far more efficient writing software to run directly on the ESP8266 rather than struggling with a ropey AT command set.

Comment: @Majenko I flashed my esp8266 and now it is working. Thanks for the Assist.

Comment: it's virtually impossible to brick an esp; all you need to do is put it in flash mode and reflash.